# Laravel 5.2 Incorrect Route Model Binding does not show 404

Tags: laravel-5, http-status-code-404, laravel-routing

In Laravel 5.2 docs about Implicit route model binding, there is written:

> If a matching model instance is not found in the database, a 404 HTTP
>   response will be automatically generated.

**Route**:

```
Route::get('/product/{product}',function(Product $product){ 
     dd($product); 
});
```

When I enter into URL parameter existent ID, everything works as expected. But when I enter into URL nonexistent product ID, I got `No query results for model [App\Product].` instead of `response 404`. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching i found out solution. If you have no specified error template files in `resources/views/errors` default Laravel message will be shown. Just create 404.blade.php file in `resources/views/errors`.