# Why the resource routes still working if the URL consists of alphanumeric for resource id | Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am working on a Laravel application and I come across a very strange issue. I have defined the routes using the Route::resource function

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');
```

and I generate the PostController using

> php artisan make:controller PostController --resource --model=Post

command so it is using Implicit Binding for Post resource.

**PostController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Post  $post
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Post $post)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Post  $post
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Post $post)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Post  $post
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Post $post)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Post  $post
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Post $post)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Now the URLs are

```
GET         /posts
GET         /posts/create
POST        /posts
GET         /posts/{post}
GET         /posts/{post}/edit
PUT/PATCH   /posts/{post}
DELETE      /posts/{post}
```

Everything is working fine. Let say I have a post whose id is 146. so the URL for the post detail page will be

```
http://localhost/laravel-app/posts/146
```

This URL is working fine. But when I open the following URL it still working.

```
http://localhost/laravel-app/posts/146re4dasdasda

http://localhost/laravel-app/posts/146re4

http://localhost/laravel-app/posts/146re
```

So I expected that the above mention URLs should return a 404 not found page. But it still shows the detail page for the post whose id is 146.

and the URLs are also working for edit, update or delete operations. i.e

```
GET         /posts/146re4/edit
PUT/PATCH   /posts/146re4
DELETE      /posts/146re4
```

Comment: add that `findOrFail` with ID, on your controller methods such as `show`, `edit`, `update`.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question I am using Implicit Binding for the controller.

Comment: Check my update question for getting the Post controller code.

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39118161/laravel-5-2-incorrect-route-model-binding-does-not-show-404), if helpful.

Comment: I have the 404 pages. Even when I open /posts/45645351 i.e the post that does not exist then It gave the 404 page.

Comment: try with route regex [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints)

Comment: Well, the regex is not working with the resource route.